# Max-height for nano scrolls the whole page up

Tags: jquery, scroll, nanoscroller

I use https://github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS
I have a container which has max-height 600px. This container has nanoScroller. And if the height of this container changes dynamically (collapsing), then the main page scroll (browser scroll) moves the page to the top. 
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's pretty vague. Need some more info than that.

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle or jsbin showing your issue and code...

Comment: I have created a plunk, here is the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/mR9FnBg0lfNSCtRPOfT6?p=preview I am using https://github.com/maxaon/angular-nanoscroller . To replicate the issue, scroll down to the page bottom and press "Add item to list". Afterwards you'll see that the browser scroll moved up. Thanks in advance.